# What are the expenditure items called?

Tags: word-request

Imagine there is a shady charity I can't trust because it is not clear where they plan to spend the donations. I would say:

> I don't trust them. The _________ of the donations are not clear.

What word(s) should I use to mean "items on which the money will be spent"? Something like *purposes* maybe?

It may be not specific to donations, rather any amount of money. For example, the list of the expenses a government spends the taxes on.

(**EDIT:** added some more details)

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Can you define "expenditure items"?

Comment: @fev sorry. I mean the list of things on which the money is spent. Like "expense1: 100$, expense2: 20$, expense3: 50$, etc."

Comment: I agree with fev.  I can't really think of a word that means "expenditure items" AND goes with "of the donations".

Comment: Donations (income) and expenditures (outflow) are opposite things; there isn't a word for both unless you want to get super-general and say something like, "The books seem to be cooked."

Comment: @FeliniusRex ok, I may have misused the word "expenditure", but the question of "how the income is spent?" is valid, right? That is what I am interested in.

Comment: @Mahm00d Yes, that's a totally valid question. Ok, I understand now.

Comment: Rather than referring to unclear *purposes* or *documentation*, perhaps what you should be concerned about is that *The **beneficiaries** of the donations are not clear* (are they *actually* using the money to help "deserving causes", or is it all being swallowed up by administration / staff costs?).

Comment: Does it have to follow this **exact** sentence format? If not, then I'd say, "I don't trust them. The **use** of the donations they receive is not clear." Even better: "**How they use** the donations they receive..."

Comment: @gotube no, it doesn't need to. But I wonder if there is a more specific (financial-related) word for this?

Comment: Oh, like accounting terminology. Sadly, there's no accounting site in Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need ***expenditure records***:

> I don't trust them. Their ***expenditure records*** are not clear.

You can omit *donations*, since *expenditure* implies spending of money.

An expenditure record is

> a written record of money spent ([vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/expense%20record))

EDIT: If you need a word for a document that will show future expenditure then use ***spending plan*** which means:

> *a plan to show how a person or an organization, especially a government, will spend the money that is available*:
>
> - Lawmakers are still working out the details of a final *spending plan*. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spending-plan))

So you can say

> I don't trust them. Their ***spending plans*** are not clear.

Comment: Thanks. But what if it is planned? Like there's a crisis and they list the things they plan to spend the donations on?

Comment: Well, you did not mention that in your question. Please edit.

Comment: I have answered your question in an edit to my answer.